# change achorpane effect after closing another screen

Tags: javafx

i have fxml file called Principale.fxml that contain a buton.
when i click on it another stage is opened and an BoxBlur effect is added to an AnchorPane in principale.fxml.
 so what iwant is to set effect as null for this AnchorPane when  i close the second stage 
here is my code:

principale.fxml

```
 info.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override
                    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                        Parent home_page_p = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/View/information.fxml"));

                        Scene home_page_s = new Scene (home_page_p);
                        javafx.scene.effect.BoxBlur bxb = new BoxBlur();
                       ancr.setEffect(bxb);

                        Stage stage = new Stage();
                        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
                        stage.setScene(home_page_s);

                        stage.show();


                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(PrincipaleController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
```

when i execute i get this
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAFqG.jpg

Information.fxml

```
public void closeApp(MouseEvent mv) throws IOException
    {
        app_stage = (Stage) close.getScene().getWindow();
        app_stage.hide();

        PrincipaleController pc = new PrincipaleController();
        pc.ancr.setEffect(null);
    }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAFqG.jpg

so when i close the information window i want to set principale.fxml effect as null, what should i add to closeapp method?

Comment: No  and i dont know how to do it im new to javafx

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your code. You shouldn't type

```
Controller ctl = new Controller();
```

rather fetch it from the FXMLLoader using

```
FXMLLoader loader = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/View/information.fxml"));
Parent home_page_p = loader.load();
Controller ctl = loader.getController();
```

Later use this to create a new stage :

```
Stage stage = new Stage();
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
ctl.Glisse(home_page_p, stage, home_page_s);
stage.setScene(home_page_s);
// Adding a event handler to be fired on the event of stage being closed
stage.setOnCloseRequest((WindowEvent event) -> {
      // Perform some action when the stage is closed
      ancr.setEffect(null); // ancr is a reference to the anchorpane
}
```

**Note :** You don't need to create another instance of `PrincipaleController` because all of the above code is written inside the `PrincipaleController class`.

Comment: well Controller is just a class that i create, its contain some method to move an undecorated stage

Comment: Each fxml file must have a controller to bind fields and properties. Please read more about it at [Introduction to FXML](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/fxml-tutorial/why_use_fxml.htm#CIHJCABJ)

Comment: :( i know but, i just created this class and i give it the name controller it contain method called glisse to move undecorated window

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show your problem. Without the complete picture I won't be able to help you better.

Comment: Please read about MCVE, but clicking on the link above. Without sufficient code I cannot suggest. Moreover, the picture you posted doesn't clarify anything about controllers.